# convert the pdf as thumbnail image and save that data into solr too?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, apache-pig, apache-tika

I am trying to convert the pdf as thumbnail image and save that data into Solr to If it is possible means please help us?

Answer (score 1):

But why MapReduce. 
you need to extract pdf first using tika refer the link below

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_extracting_pdf.htm

get metedata names and its values and create JSON. something like

pdftitle:two states

author:chetan bhagat

to

{
"pdftitle":"two states",
"author":"chetan bhagat"
}